# Why does accessing binding's views in dynamic feature module cause NullPointerException error?

Tags: android-instant-apps, google-instant

When data binding is used inside dynamic feature module layout files and the same views/widgets I try to access inside fragment or activity throws NullPointerException error.

At same time if I try to access same view with findById it works perfectly. If the layout file is starting and ending with "<layout>" tag it gives the error, if it's removed the the code works perfectly. I tried all possible solutions and both data and view binding is turned on through Gradle. I have following app structure app -> works with dependency of base base -> contain all base functions and code dynamicFeature -> works with dependency of base and app.

The dynamic feature module should not give null pointer when view is accessed through ViewDataBinding layouts created with "<layout>" tag in it.

minSdk 26
maxSdk 33
compileSdk 33

Comment: Hi @girish, did you find any solution for this? I'm also running behind this issue.